# VBA - random number between two values

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen multiple answers say the following algorithm works fine to generate a random number between two values. I'm getting spurious results where I'll sometimes get a value returned that is higher than the upper bound.

```
Dim random as Integer
random = Int (3 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0
Debug.Print random
```

This should give values between 0 - 3 right? I'm seeing 0 to 4 when run a few times..???

[image]

Comment: `In Excel VBA, it might be easier to just use Application.RandBetween(0,3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the idiosyncrasies of VBA.

You can see the effect more clearly by writing

```
random = Int(4) * Rnd
```

`4 * Rnd` is a *floating point double* type, and when it gets assigned to `random`, The same rounding convention as for `CInt` is applied<sup>1</sup>; i.e. if `Int(4) * Rnd` is 3.5 or greater, the result is 4.

The fix is to write

```
random = Int(4 * Rnd)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The convention "round half to even" is often called *Banker's Rounding*. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: Rounding a number to cast it to an integer is as much acceptable as a truncating it. `Rnd()` generates a number from 0.0 included to 1.0 excluded, so a simple `random = 3 * Rnd` will match the range `[0:3]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to be expected when explicitly converting floating point number to integer, but what might not be expected is that the rounding is towards the closest even number:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 3.5           ' i = 4
i = "2.5"         ' i = 2
```